# Rasterize Holoviews DynamicMap with Overlay and Layout

Tags: python, holoviews, rasterizing, datashader

I have an DynamicMap in Holoviews with the call function returning a Layout Object of Multiple Overlays. The structure is basically like this:

Dynamic Map -> Layouts (2 Columns of 9 Overlays) -> Overlay from 8-9 Curves.

I want to rasterize this DynamicMap but don't know how to start. I tried `rasterize(DynamicMap)` but it returned
[image]

I also tried to rasterize from the curve elements themselves but they returned empty DynamicMaps.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to debug this without a reproducible example. If you can make one small enough to post here, someone could take a look!